# Text in sidebar not being displayed during run time mac desktop application

Tags: macos, user-interface, cocoa, sidebar

I used a Source list to create a sidebar for the mac OS application i'm making but it doesn't seem to display the text in the sidebar when i run the application. Here's how it looks when in the editor [image: how it looks like in xcode]

Here's how it looks like when I run it [image: sidebar on run time]

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it.
Also I haven't implemented any code for this I simply dragged and dropped the UI element into the view and then fixed the constraints issue using "Resolve Auto Layout Issues" any help would be great.

Comment: See [NSOutlineView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsoutlineview) and the linked [Navigating Hierarchical Data Using Outline and Split Views](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/cocoa_bindings/navigating_hierarchical_data_using_outline_and_split_views). Which text do you want to dsplay in the sidebar?

Comment: the first picture shows home i wanted to display 2 more elements like settings and about information for example like in a normal sidebar and when clicked on the show different views(a different screen with different elements) i think(sorry i'm new to mac application building).

Comment: Try to find a tutorial like [NSOutlineView on macOS Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1201-nsoutlineview-on-macos-tutorial) on raywenderlich.com.